# Loop through childs of TreeView.Items

Tags: c#, wpf

i got this loop here:

```
 foreach (object obje in this.treeViewSL.Items)
 {
     TreeViewItem TVI = (TreeViewItem)treeViewSL.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(obje);

     if ((TVI.Header.ToString() == _object.NodeText)) 
     {
         TVI.IsSelected = true;
         TVI.IsExpanded = true;
         _selectedItem = treeViewSL.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
         continue;
     }                       
 }
```

this works fine to look if there is treeviewitem with this header in the first items, but it seems that treeviewsl.Items doesn't count the childs, it gives me 1 back but there are 3, so 1 root with 2 childs, how i can loop through these also?

Comment: The treeview has one child, the root node. The root node has two children. You need to do this recursively. Are you familiar with writing recursive functions? You should in any case be setting those properties via data binding, but given your use of `continue;`, let's take it one step at a time.

Comment: so i need a recursive function which goes always like treeview.items.items.items....

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "goes always like treeview.items.items.items"

Comment: i need to loop through the treeview items, not the data itself, because i get here random data which attatch random nodes in the treeview